# In Python, how do I skip an item in a list when using nested for loops, but only in certain conditions?

Tags: python, for-loop

It's a pretty niche situation I've come across, but I need to reuse one list in multiple nested for loops and also avoid repeats.  Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
my_list = [7,1,4,2,6,5,3]
for x in my_list:
  for y in my_list:
    if y == x:
      #advance to the next item in my_list
    for z in my_list:
      while z == x or z == y:
        #advance to the next item in my_list
      #do stuff
```

I am also wondering if there is a cleaner way to avoid repeats than using the while loop, because the loop is going to be nested up to 9 times, so it would make for messy while loops.  I tried converting my_list to an iterator using iter(my_list) and then using y = next(my_list), which normally would work, but then the next for loop with z will not start at the beginning of my_list.  The only solution I can think of is to use while loops instead of for loops so I can do something like the following:

```
z = 0
while z < 7:
  while z == y or z == x:
    z += 1
  #do stuff with my_list[z]
  z += 1
```

I'd really like to avoid this approach if possible.  Is there any way I can do it using for loops?

EDIT: Commented out the lines that aren't code

Comment: Why a "while" in the first code snippet instead of an "if... : continue"?

Comment: I'd say you really wanna look at if else cases.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I didn't realize that 'continue' was a keyword.  I'm still extremely new to Python.  Continue does exactly what I need, thank you!  In fact, that fixes both of my problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pass` to not do anything, for example:

```
L = [1, 2, 0, 4]
for element in L:
    if element == 0:
        pass
    else:
        print(element)
```

This will print: 1, 2 and 4 since it will skip 0

If you want to stop the current loop, use `break`:

```
for element in L:
    if element == 0:
        break
    else:
        print(element)
```

This will print out 1, 2 and then the loop stops.

So, which one you use depends on how you want to advance to the next item. `break` will stop the current for loop and take you back to the previous for loop, while `pass` will continue the loop but just not do anything with that element